# RightClick menu in VB.Net Custom Control

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

As the title say: I create a custom control which is composed by a picturebox, checkbox, label etc ..

I was needy to show a menu by mouse rightclick, but the event was only invoked when I click on the backgroud layout and not when I click on the picturebox or the checkbox.

What I wnat is how to be able to show a menu when I RightClick on my custom control whatever the location is (on the picturebox, the label ...) in order to avoid the copy/paste for the MouseUp event of each subcontrol of my Custom Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel. This is already implemented by the [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Create a new [ContextMenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set the [ContextMenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of each control (including the custom control) to  this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code to know exactly what you're doing, you need to make sure that you set your `ContextMenuStrip` property for *all* child controls, not just your user control itself:

```
Public Class UserControl
    Private _mainMenu As New ContextMenuStrip()

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        _mainMenu.Items.Add("FirstMenuItem")
        PictureBox1.ContextMenuStrip = _mainMenu
        CheckBox1.ContextMenuStrip = _mainMenu
        Me.ContextMenuStrip = _mainMenu
    End Sub
End Class
```